# Excel 2013, can data be re-sorted automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, microsoft-excel-2013

Is there a way to re-sort automatically? I have automatically updating cells and depending on incoming values the rankings change. I am looking for a way to have the table resort automatically (similar to conditional formatting) without having to click the re-sort button.

The goal here is to accomplish such purely through a built-in Excel2013 function. I am not looking for a solution that involves additional cells that aide the sort, such as Rank(),...

**Edit**

I include the code of a macro that refreshes the workbook at set interval and also included code within one worksheet that is supposed to refresh the tables on that one sheet on Worksheet_Calculate. I am getting a runtime error not sure what is wrong?

```vb
Public RunWhen As Double
Const frequency = 5
Const cRunWhat = "DoIt"  ' the name of the procedure to run

Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, frequency)
    Application.OnTime RunWhen, cRunWhat, Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub DoIt()
    Sheets("RAWDATA").Calculate
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    StartTimer  ' Reschedule the procedure
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime RunWhen, cRunWhat, Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

**and the code that supposedly refreshes the tables**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Strategies").ListObjects("Table2").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Strategies").ListObjects("Table3").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, I think this link should show a way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020878/auto-sort-and-format-and-excel

Comment: So, I take it there is no function within Excel2013 that activates automated re-sorting of tables? I am surprised about that because conditional formatting adjusts automatically on any changes in source data. So, I find it hard to believe that no sorting functionality exists that re-sorts on changing data. I understand that I can simply record a macro and re-sort manually and plug the code into the WorkshSeet_Change() event method, but its extremely dirty, the slightest change in column renaming breaks the code to just name one issue.

Comment: The "screen flickers" can be avoided if you use `Application.Screenupdating` True / False. First you type False to disable showing any updates made to worksheet and then True to show you what have been done.

Comment: Another thing about Worksheets_change is to create good `if` condition, so the macro will not react every time you move to another cell.

Comment: well just played with it and Worksheet_Change seems to be much better than sticking the macro into Worksheet_Calculate, for whatever reason. Runs pretty smoothly now and I guess I can just go with that for the time being. Thanks

Comment: Well, anwsered is pretty simple `Worksheet_Calculate` works when you change `formula`. I suppose your data are not formulas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a dynamic sorting feature in Excel 2007/2010?](http://superuser.com/questions/609523/is-there-a-dynamic-sorting-feature-in-excel-2007-2010)

Comment: To add on to the comment by @lowak regarding good `if` statements in `worksheet_change` events: I've found the best method is to use `if( not( intersect( YOURSHEET.RANGE(YOURRANGE), TARGET) IS NOTHING)) THEN...` as the test. The range held in TARGET is the range that caused the `Worksheet_Change` event to trigger. That quick test will check whether the triggering range instersects with the range you want to test and will keep the sheet from resorting every time you sneeze.

Comment: @lowak, thanks for your offer to get back on this, I find problems with my current macro within Worksheet_Calculate. My settings to Calculate are always set to manual, and I already run another macro that refreshes the whole workbook at specified intervals. My problem is that sometimes when I start the macro that refreshes at specified intervals I get a run time error that originates from the newly inserted macros that refresh the tables. I edited my question to show some code, do you mind taking a look? Thanks

Comment: Where excacly do you get that error? Which macros are "newly inserted"? I think your errors may occur in "DoIt" and "StartTimer".

Comment: @lowak, the newly inserted is the last code block which runs in `WorkSheet_Calculate()`. The first code block that schedules workbook recalculation sits in "General" and the `StartTimer()` method is invoked upon the click of a button in one of the worksheets. I think I may have found the problem: The code that re-sorts the tables is referenced on `ActiveSheet` which is not correct when being on a different sheet and kicking off the "Workbook re-calculation macro"

Comment: Hm... If you want to calculate it only when you are in Worksheet "Strategies" then paste this condition: `If ActiveSheet.Name = "Strategies" Then` and adjust it to your needs :)

Comment: @Iowak, if you like please write up an answer and I will mark it as sought-after. Thanks again for your valuable help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like leaving questions unanswered when they've already been answered it he comments. You can read the history in the comments but here is the final solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    'If the active sheet is called "Strategies", then this reapplies the filter for two tables and re-sorts them

    Const wsName As String = "Strategies"

    If ActiveSheet.Name = wsName Then

        'Freeze everything and turn off events
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
            .DisplayAlerts = False
        End With

        'Update Table2
        With Worksheets(wsName).ListObjects("Table2")
            .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
            With .Sort
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
        End With

        'Update Table3
        With Worksheets(wsName).ListObjects("Table3")
            .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
            With .Sort
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
        End With

        'Unfreeze things and turn events back on
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
            .DisplayAlerts = True
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

You could probably even shorten the filtering and sorting to just

```
    With Worksheets(wsName).ListObjects("Table2")
        .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
        .Sort.Apply
    End With
```

<sub>This is a community wiki because I did not derive the solution. You can edit it if you want but all I did was transcribe the problem found in the comments and clean up the code a bit.</sub>