# Automatically updating bar chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

So for a project at work I have a table in excel that contains numbers for each month of the year up to this one in four categories. It looks (a bit) like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Group | Jan   | Feb   |   Mar | Apr   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| AAAA  |   111 |   222 |   333 |   444 |
| BBBB  |   555 |   666 |   777 |   888 |
| CCCC  |   999 |   000 |   111 |   222 |
| DDDD  |   333 |   444 |   555 |   666 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

What I'm trying to do now is to create a bar chart that displays all four groups as groups of bars that contain the data for the current month, the one 6 Months and one year ago.
Now to do this once would be quite easy, but I'm trying to make it so that when I ad a new month, it automatically updates the whole chart.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Maybe this will give a hint: http://superuser.com/questions/738577/excel-2013-can-data-be-re-sorted-automatically

Comment: @lowak so vba is the way to go then.. I was kind of hoping to get another answer but oh well :/

Comment: Unless something like this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183446

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using an Excel Table for this.

1. Convert your data to an Excel Table, `Insert > Table`.
2. Add 3 columns (after your group, before your months), called Current, 6_Prior, 12_Prior (or something else suitable).
3. Use the following formula's for the three added columns (change reference names as appropriate):

   > **Current:** =OFFSET([@Current],0,COLUMNS(Table)-2)
   >   **6_Prior:** =OFFSET([@6_Prior],0,COLUMNS(Table)-8)
   >   **12_Prior:** =OFFSET([@12_Prior],0,COLUMNS(Table)-14)

   Assuming that you add the new months' data to the right of the table, this will return the newest month, and the 6 and 12 prior.
4. Create your chart using the Current, 6_Prior and 12_Prior columns as your data source.  The chart will automatically update as you add data to your Table.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Name Manager. Create new name called `Month`.
2. Under Refers to, change it to `=OFFSET("Group",0,0,1,COUNTA(1:1))`
3. Create a bar chart using existing data.
4. Click the bar chart in the figure. The formula should be something like this:

`=SERIES(Sheet1!$D$9,Sheet1!$E$7:$I$7,Sheet1!$E$9:$I$9,2)`

Change the second part, `Sheet1!$E$7:$I$7` to `Month`.

The chart will now auto update like you want.